# Find a number $n \neq 2017$ such that $\phi(n) = \phi(2017)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Find a number $n \neq 2017$ such that $\phi(n) = \phi(2017)$, as above. I know the formula for a general $\phi$ function, but I cannot see how this is helpful here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could work out $\phi(2017)$ for a start?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Yes, I think I can figure this out, but I'm quite stuck after here..

Comment: if $p$ is odd then $\phi(2p)=\phi(2)\phi(p)=\phi(p)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $2017$ is a prime number.

**Solution:** Fortunately, the totient function $\phi$ has the nice property that $\phi(p) = \phi(2p)$, where $p$ is prime. This is because $2p$ is relatively prime to all odd numbers less than it except $p$. There are $p$ even numbers less than $2p$, and discounting the fact that $\gcd(p, 2p) \neq 1$, we see that $$\phi(2p) = p - 1 = \phi(p)$$
You could have alternatively seen this from the multiplicative property of $\phi$, namely that $\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)$.
Hence, $\phi(4034) = \phi(2017)$, because $\phi(2) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I see that. So $\phi(2017) = 2016$. How does this fact help answering this question?

Comment: @RnHdw See my edits.

Comment: I saw that $2017$ is prime but didn't think of  $4034.$ I found $\phi(29\cdot 73)=(28)(72)=(2^5)(7)(9)=2016.$